# How to replace form text string with div text

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form and I am using an `onkeyup` event to search for **matches** within a database based on what the **user types**. That part is **working** just fine. Results **trigger** a hidden DIV to be shown with matches.

What I would then like to do is **allow** the user to click a matching result and using `onclick` have that result **inserted** into the text field the user was typing in.

Here is what I have:

HTML

```
Distributor
<font color="red"><b>*</b></font>
<input type="text"
       name="dist" 
       id="dist" 
       value="<? if (isset($dist)) {echo $dist;} ?>" required 
       onkeyup="sugdist(this.value);"/>
<br><br>
```

SCRIPT

```
function fillDist() {

var insertText = $(this).text();
   $('#dist').insert(insertText);
}
```

Here is what I have on the AJAX script side.

```
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<div id='fillDist' OnClick='fillDist'>"
           .addslashes($result->name).
         "</div>";
}
```

**It's not working, but its also not tripping any errors.**

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of the function that runs when the user clicks the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow is not so clear.
So, the AJAX script returns an HTML that has an `onClick` function.
I am assuming that the output is correctly added to your output div, because I see a simple error here:

```
OnClick='fillDist'
```

you should change it to

```
onClick='fillDist()'
```

to really call the function.

However, you have the jQuery tag and you are using it in some other operations, so you can avoid the inline `onClick` in the HTML code, and do it all javascript/jQuery side:

```
$(document).on('click', '#fillDist', function() {
  const text = $(this).text();
  $('#dist').text(text);
});
```

We are doing this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dist', function() {});
```

and not this:

```
$('#dist').click(function() {});
```

Because the element is dynamically injected.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#fillDist', function() {
  const text = $(this).text();
  $('#dist').text(text);
});
```

```css
#dist {
  margin: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dist">
  
</div>

<div id="fillDist">click me to add the same text to dist</div>
```

Please find the demo even [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/lorenzos/pen/OaOpVd).

Comment: This works brilliantly for adding the text in a div. I cannot get it to insert the text into the form field.

Comment: Was able to do it with: `$('#dist').val(text);`